# Which minimum amount of RAM is needed to boot the Arch Linux live iso?

Tags: arch-linux, memory, livecd

The [Arch wiki installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) lists that more then a minimum of 512 MiB RAM is needed to boot the live installer.

Other users noted that [ArchISO 202005 breaks with 512MB of RAM](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-releng/2020-May/003957.html).

I can confirm that iso 202002 still boots OK with 512 MiB of memory. Release 202003 fails back to interactive rootfs prompt with logged errors:

> Initramfs unpacking failed: write error

and

> /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_202003 device did not show up after 30 seconds.

Which minimum amount of memory is needed to boot the Arch Linux live iso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 740 MiB

Trial and error in a VM with 4 MiB increments, it turns out that the minimum amount of RAM for "current" **archlinux-2022.09.03-x86_64** is 740 MB

### History

- 720 MiB of RAM is required for the old archlinux-2021.07.01-x86_64.
- 656 MiB of RAM is required for the old archlinux-2021.02.01-x86_64.
- 520 MiB for the first release (archlinux-2020.03.01-x86_64.iso) that did no longer boot with 512 MiB.